# How to set path to protrator?

Tags: selenium, protractor

im getting this error message while running protactor

error message:

```
protractor : The term 'protractor' is not      
recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function,  
script file, or operable program. Check the    
spelling of the name, or if a path was         
included, verify that the path is correct and  
try again.
```

I deleted my node_modules folder by accident but then added it again and im getting this error while running protractor or webdriver-manager

im getting this error while trying to do

```
npm install -g protractor
```

```
npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
npm ERR! code EPERM
npm ERR! syscall unlink
npm ERR! path C:\Users\145702\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\.webdriver-manager.DELETE\selenium\MicrosoftWebDriver.exe
npm ERR! errno -4048
npm ERR! Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink 'C:\Users\145702\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\.webdriver-manager.DELETE\selenium\MicrosoftWebDriver.exe'
npm ERR!  [OperationalError: EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink 'C:\Users\145702\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\.webdriver-manager.DELETE\selenium\MicrosoftWebDriver.exe'] {
npm ERR!   cause: [Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink 'C:\Users\145702\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\.webdriver-manager.DELETE\selenium\MicrosoftWebDriver.exe'] {
npm ERR!     errno: -4048,
npm ERR!     code: 'EPERM',
npm ERR!     syscall: 'unlink',
npm ERR!     path: 'C:\\Users\\145702\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\protractor\\node_modules\\.webdriver-manager.DELETE\\selenium\\MicrosoftWebDriver.exe'
npm ERR!   },
npm ERR!   stack: "Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink 'C:\\Users\\145702\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\protractor\\node_modules\\.webdriver-manager.DELETE\\selenium\\MicrosoftWebDriver.exe'",
npm ERR!   errno: -4048,
npm ERR!   code: 'EPERM',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'unlink',
npm ERR!   path: 'C:\\Users\\145702\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\protractor\\node_modules\\.webdriver-manager.DELETE\\selenium\\MicrosoftWebDriver.exe',
npm ERR!   parent: 'protractor'
npm ERR! }
npm ERR!
npm ERR! The operation was rejected by your operating system.
npm ERR! It's possible that the file was already in use (by a text editor or antivirus),
npm ERR! or that you lack permissions to access it.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the
npm ERR! permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running
npm ERR! the command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\145702\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-04-22T00_49_43_150Z-debug.log
```

Answer (score 0):

run this command :   `npm install -g protractor`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

1. Uninstall protractor by below command.

```
npm uninstall -g protractor
```

2. Delete protractor folder from below directory location if exist.
   C:\Users\145702\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\
3. Delete protractor windows cmd file from below location if exist.
   C:\Users\145702\AppData\Roaming\npm
4. Install protractor again.

```
npm install -g protractor
```

One good practise, Don't install protractor globally. Do install at project level and use it.

Comment: hello, I had to delete a folder that was being created in my node modules for the webdriver-manager that was impeding the installation of protractor, its working again, thanks